# Shortcut to checking if a value exist in an object

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to get a shortcut to return a value in an object. For example,

```
const days = {
 Monday: 4,
 Thursday: 3,
 Friday: 1
}
```

Now, if I want to do `days.Thursday`, that value will be undefined, so if I do `days.Thursday`, it will return undefined, but I would like for it to return 0, if it is undefined.
My method of doing this would be to do:

```
days.Thursday?days.Thursday:0
```

But doing this is very repetitive and I'd have to do it at least 7 times, for each day of the week, considering this object is being set based off of data from firebase.

Comment: just have the defaults object `{Monday: 0, Tuesday: 0, Wednesday...` and do `allDays = {...defaults, ...days}`. `allDays` will have zeroes on empty days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `??` (the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)) to default to a different value if the expression on the left is undefined (or null):

```
const thursdayVal = days.Thursday ?? 0;
```

> I'd have to do it at least 7 times, for each day of the week

Consider iterating over an array of property names instead, eg

```
const dayNames = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', /* ... */];
for (const dayName of dayNames) {
  // do something with days[dayName] ?? 0
}
```

Comment: Oh nice, didnt even know this existed. Thanks

Comment: Th old style expression `days.Thursday || 0` will work in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The cross browser solution will be double pipe syntax

```
var value = days.Thursday || 0;
```